# Implemeting delayed execution with rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to implement sort of delayed execution on some action. For example, when you type in a search string and don't want for search to send a server request until user stops printing. Kind of what we all see in search engines like google, etc. What is the best way to implement that with rxjs?

Comment: [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#debouncing-requests)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `FormControl` and listen for changes using this snippet:

```
<input [formControl]="control">

... 

public control = new FormControl();

this.control.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe((value: string) => {

    // Do stuff with the value
  }
);
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [debounceTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime)  operator for that:

```
const textInput$ = fromEvent(this.yourInput.nativeElement, 'keyup');

textInput$.pipe(
  debounceTime(500), // discard emitted values that take less than 500ms
  switchMap(text => this.getSearch(text)) // getSearch is your request to the server
)
.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like the classic typeahead functionality.

I would recommend reading about the `debounceTime()` operator.
[Typeahead](https://www.learnrxjs.io/recipes/type-ahead.html)

This will stop accepting additional requests until a certain time has passed and onle then pass your request through.